# RelativeLayout issues

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I'm starting developing for `Android` and the layout system seems to be quite difficult compared to iOS. I have a `RelativeLayout` with 4 `ImageView`s. The most right `ImageView` should be vertically in the middle of the screen. The other 3 `ImageView`s should be placed left to it. After switching from a `LinearLayout` to a `RelativeLayout` (still don't know if this was clever) as soon as I add this line

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/moto_icon"
```

to the left items (moto icon for the first item [cloud1], cloud1 for the second item, etc.) the `ImageView`s of the clouds disappear.

This is my entire layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="de.manuel_schulze.motorradonline.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/splashScreen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/moto_icon"
                android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="42dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/moto_icon"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cloud1"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/moto_icon"
                android:src="@drawable/cloud"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cloud2"
                android:layout_width="12dp"
                android:layout_height="12dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/cloud1"
                android:src="@drawable/cloud"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cloud3"
                android:layout_width="16dp"
                android:layout_height="16dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/cloud2"
                android:src="@drawable/cloud"/>

        </RelativeLayout>


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/motorrad_logo" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

If I run the app in the emulator the 3 clouds does not show up. In the design tap I see just blue arrows.

[image]

Do you have some ideas on fixing the `RelativeLayout` or an alternative?

**EDIT:** What I want is this:

[image]

Comment: Just a quick question that came to my mind on reading your xml: Why you not writing the "content" code in content.xml file? After all you have this include statement:  <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

Comment: post a screenshot of what u want?

Comment: @CasualCoder: You're correct, I moved it into the content_main. First I wanted it to be in the app_bar_main because it should appear as fullscreen. But I had to hide the ActionBar anyway. But the Images still don't show up.

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 I added an image of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following code: Replace your inner Linearlayout `android:id="@+id/splashScreen"`  with:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/splashScreen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/moto_icon"
            android:layout_width="56dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cloud1"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/moto_icon"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cloud2"
            android:layout_width="12dp"
            android:layout_height="12dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/cloud1"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cloud3"
            android:layout_width="16dp"
            android:layout_height="16dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/cloud2"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    </RelativeLayout>


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. The images are now all centered but I still only see the moto_icon.

Comment: it shows in my case...remove this line `<include layout="@layout/content_main" />` and see..also make sure u replace the whole layout.

Comment: Thanks now it works. I think I still had something missing.

Answer (score 0):

For the most right Image set this :

```
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

this will bring it to center vertically

and for the rest do what you do and use `android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/some_id"`

but in this scenerio your most right image will be in the left and other images will not be shown. I did not exactly get what you are trying to do it but to make your image very center use `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` or give it an enough left margin `android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/some_dimen"` so let the images in the left shown in the screen.

Or simlpy use a linear layout with a horizontal orientation

hope it helps

edit : I saw your image now, use centerInParent attribute. That is what you need